# rsplit on pandas series with regular expression not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

rsplit on pandas series using regular expression not working. I want to split the series based on separator without removing separator.

```
df2= pd.Series(['Series of Class A','Series of Class B part of Class C','Class D','Class'])
seperator='Class'
data = df2.str.split(r'.(?='+seperator+')', n = 2, expand=True)
```

result is:

```
 0                1        2
0  Series of          Class A     None
1  Series of  Class B part of  Class C
2    Class D             None     None
3      Class             None     None
```

I want to do same thing using rsplit

I tried

```
data = df2.str.rsplit(r'.(?='+seperator+')', n = 2, expand=True)
```

Expecting same result using rsplit

```
 0                1        2
0  Series of          Class A     None
1  Series of  Class B part of  Class C
2    Class D             None     None
3      Class             None     None
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `pd.Series.str.rsplit` does not work as documented ([v0.25](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), [stable/v1+](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)). The project's GitHub issue tracker has an [open bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29633) from Nov. 2019 that repots that `rsplit` is not working with regex patterns (v 0.24.2 and 0.25.2). Internally, the method is calling [`str.rsplit`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html) which does not support regular expressions.

Luckily, the reporter jamespreed added a (homegrown) alternative [function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29633#issuecomment-556008640):

> ```
> def str_rsplit(arr, pat=None, n=None):
>
>     if pat is None or len(pat) == 1:
>         if n is None or n == 0:
>             n = -1
>         f = lambda x: x.rsplit(pat, n)
>     else:
>         if n is None or n == -1:
>             n = 0
>         regex = re.compile(pat)
>         def f(x):
>             s = regex.split(x)
>             a, b = s[:-n], s[-n:]
>             if not a:
>                 return b
>             ix = 0
>             for a_ in a:
>                 ix = x.find(a_, ix) + len(a_)
>             x_ = [x[:ix]]
>             return x_ + b
>     return f
>     res = _na_map(f, arr)
>     return res
> ```