# Split column based on last digit found

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column containing an address and some text after it.

ex:

```
Address
123 Fake St, Boulder, CO 80304 Attached Dwelling/
345 Main St, Boulder, CO 80304 Vacant Land/Lots
456 Cool Dr, Erie, CO 80516 Attached Dwelling/Building
```

This is what I'd like to do

```
Address                               Type
123 Fake St, Boulder, CO 80304        Attached Dwelling/
345 Main St, Boulder CO 80304         Vacant Land/Lots
456 Cool Dr, Erie, Co 80516           Attached Dwelling/Building
```

I thought this might work, using regex to look for the first digit, but working from right to left. However, I get the error "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

```
df[['Address', 'Type']] = df['Address'].str.rsplit('\d', n=1, expand=True)
```

Comment: don't you mean based on the last digit? if you split on first digit you will have 123 then another column.

Comment: Thanks for that. Corrected the title :)

Comment: Just split on the space immediately to the left of the last digit found. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please `split` on the space that has five digits immediately to its left and expand split if you wanted to use `split`

```
 df.Address.str.split('(?<=\d{5})\s+', expand=True)


                         0                           1
0  123 Fake St, Boulder, CO 80304          Attached Dwelling/
1  345 Main St, Boulder, CO 80304            Vacant Land/Lots
2     456 Cool Dr, Erie, CO 80516  Attached Dwelling/Building
```

Comment: Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a known issue of `rsplit` not working with regex ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455173/rsplit-on-pandas-series-with-regular-expression-not-working), [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29633)).